# Doing a PFQuery using a NSPredicate filter on an array of objects in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, nspredicate, pfquery

I am trying to filter through an array of results called `matches` using the NSPredicate class. Although I am getting the error: `'Cannot do a comparison query for type: Swift._NSSwiftArrayImpl'`. I'm sure theres a way you can do it on arrays I just don't know it. code:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "user1 = %@ AND user2 = %@", matched, self.user) 
     let roomQuery = PFQuery(className: "Room", predicate: pred)
     if var result = roomQuery.getFirstObject() {
}
}
```

I want to see if anything of the results in `matched` are equal to any of the key values in `user1`

Thanks